# TypeScript type declaration for "member should not exist on this type"?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in a TypeScript record type to assert that the type must not contain a property with a particular name?

The use case is where we're using the presence of a particular property at runtime to tell the difference between an object that implements a particular interface vs. a property bag for specifying named arguments.

For example: [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJQRwAm6IANgJ7IBGcUAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL64YAVxAIwwcshgAKBp2YYsAHxwxMCzHwCUOfMgD0%205JwhhkcNJmSg2cURAA0yCMDAALaOZbJ3KOUIBbCHBkdCgvc2QQOCCScyhOPQRyNil1SywAXmQAcjV0HOsQeM5kAH4SgDp85GY5XgIiMCEoYvzK%20iheAVwECjgWbwBZKkUARmsAgAcKCCDwb0VdAnyNLJxjUzoGaR1sQlMW4py4WgQc7mQ%20K8vDZAB3O0gSZmTp4FnnKCgw5A8iPQmMydXYbJpHHxuYAsaqYDoMS4CAR9AbDUaYABMkxmc2CYEWVjwK3SbA4IFK2RynQuBiMj3AEBeyDeUw%20KGgP3C-wggK2IL2B2arUh0Nh6ER-FwdxAWBZbPCHLC3ggAA8phAxIypD8AiLvCjBr1%20oNkCNFABmbGzeb4jLLTbAnYC8HCnIeCgUAoSgRAA)

```js
interface Foo {
  readonly bar: string;
}
function f(arg: Foo | {foo: Foo}) {
  // get a Foo instance, either as the argument or as a named arg
  const foo: Foo = 'foo' in arg ? arg.foo : arg;
  return foo.bar;
}
```

We'd like to warn implementers of the `Foo` interface that they must not have a property called `foo` on their type.  For example, we'd like this code to cause a compile error:

```js
class MyFoo1 implements Foo {
  foo: Foo = { get bar() { return 'abc'; } }; // wanted: compile error here
  get bar() { return this.foo.bar; }
}
class MyFoo2 implements Foo {
  foo: string = 'bar'; // wanted: compile error here
  get bar() { return this.foo; }
}
// no compiler errors expected from this class
class MyFoo3 implements Foo {
  get bar() { return 'hello'; }
}
```

Can we do this?

The possible solutions I've considered are:

1. `never` - This one will produce an error, but it also claims that this property actually exists, which seems wrong.

```js
interface Foo {
  foo: never;
  bar: string;
}
```

2. `undefined` - This seems closer to what we want, but won't it still show up in IDE autocomplete when it never exists?

```js
interface Foo {
  foo?: undefined;
  bar: string;
}
```

3. conditional type - This one seems the most promising, but I'm not sure how to make a non-generic conditional type so that callers could say `class MyFoo2 implements Foo` not `class MyFoo2 implements Foo<SomethingElse>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick you want is:

```
interface Foo {
  foo?: never
  readonly bar: string;
}
```

This tells typescript that `foo` either must be omitted, or it must have a type of `never`, which is *never* allowed. This reduces to just the fact that it must be omitted.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYD8AXMiBAG7T7JQRwAm6IANgJ7IBGcU5AZzBRQAcwDcuAL64YAVxAIwwVoQAUfUeQxYAPjiLptmKQEocdAPSXkoiGGRw0mZKCFxFEADTIIwMAAW0I4CyIEomnIAthDgyOhQIY4UcDFMjlCidAisQo46xlgAvMhqAOSGZa4gGaLIAGT1tQB0hubELYbI5JqSBAxgclA1cDrNvFCSMrgIbHACoQCyHDoAjK5RAA5sEDHgoToWBIaFyCXYtvY8fGrmFwNDNWVw3Ahl4shSnx-WyADuHkgTHIOS2wB2vigUASyCCDDodgcE1uOHo9keYQCwAErUw4z4HxkMlm8yWK0wACYNttdrEwAcXHhjphBMIxGdkGUJu9kL8AeAIMDkKDNuCUNBoYk4RAEVdkXc0YNhpjsbj0ITpLhfiAsCKxYkJQlQhAAB6bCBKQWEaFRFWhEkLGZzBbIZY6ADM1J2e3pziwTMuSJuCoeyrKQTYbHQPKJuCAA)

---

Note that I did have to change your runtime code a tiny bit to get this to compile.

```
const aFoo: Foo = ('foo' in arg && arg.foo) ? arg.foo : arg;
```

Typescript wasn't quite smart enough to infer that the branch of the union there, because it's hard to tell the difference at runtime from an omitted prop and a prop with a value of `undefined`. By forcing it to check that `arg.foo` has a truthy value it then knows that `arg` must be of type `{ foo: Foo }`.